# How to keep flink batch job running continuously on local

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-batch

I am practicing file reading through the flink batch processing mechanism on a Windows 10 machine.

I downloaded flink-1.7.2-bin-hadoop24-scala_2.12.tgz from flink's official site and executed start-cluster.bat .

I uploaded the jar though Flink's UI and was able to execute the job but the job finished in a matter of seconds.

I want to keep the job running continuously so that I can test my use case .

Can you guide my possible ways to achieve this?

Comment: What does it mean to keep a batch job running continuously?

Comment: @DavidAnderson: Job should be running continously untill and unless i stop it manually.

Comment: Why not run it with DataStream API instead?

Answer (score 1):

In Flink, batch jobs run until all of their input has been processed, at which point they have finished and are terminated. If you want continuous processing, then you should either

- use some deployment automation (outside of Flink) to arrange for new batch jobs to be created as needed, or
- implement a streaming job

In your case it sounds like you might be looking for the `FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY` option on `StreamExecutionEnvironment.readfile` -- see the [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/overview/#data-sources) for more info.

Comment: Do you have any example program to refer it?

Comment: To the point number 2 "implement a streaming job" : What sort of implementation can be done.Can you little more elaborate?